# How to pause listening to the ng Websocket when reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, websocket

I'm using angular ui , I've created a directive that its controller listen to the websockets server and retrieve the data, actually it works fine but when leaving the page that loads the directive the socket client is still listening, my question how to pause listening until the user open the page that loads this directive again then resume listening?

I'm using this module : https://github.com/wilk/ng-websocket

**What is the best way to pause listening and resume it? and is it efficient to stop listening and start it again? what is good and bad about this methodology ?**

Edit : add some code to clarify

```
function startWS(host, port, token) {
      ws = $websocket.$new({
          url: 'ws://' + host + ':' + port + '?token=' + token,
          reconnect: true,
          reconnectInterval: 500
      });

      ws.$on('$open', function () {
          console.log('Web Socket Opened');
      });

      ws.$on('$close', function () {
          console.log('Web Socket Closed');
      });

      ws.$on('$message', function (action) {
          console.log(action);
      });
  }
```

this function is the function used to connect to the websocket, i need some other function to pause this listening and other for resuming.

Comment: sharing some of your code will help people find a solution for your problem. :)

Comment: Added some code now, nothing specific, i'm asking about a concept, is that valid or not ?

Comment: You can't pause, but you can close and reopen the connection.
Set the `reconnect: false`

Comment: setting *reconnect: false* is risky when the server is already down for some reason and i'm in the same listening page

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on how often the controller/directive will be called. You could watch for the $destroy event on the directive scope. Then you can close the connection. But this can cause many reconnects. I would probably set the connection on app init and rely on that conn. You could set an additional boolean that defines if the messages from the websocket server should be ignored or not. This boolean has to be globally available in your app. I hope i understood your question.